# Copy tables from one server to another in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, table, server

I am trying to copy a number of tables from one server to another using PostgreSQL as part of reorganising our data structure. I am pretty new to PostgreSQL so haven't much experience with it. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Probably easiest just to use the standard backup-restore if the aim is to make a copy without changes in schema http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup.html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Command-line dump straight into psql is the best bet

```
pg_dump -h host1 -t yourtable database1 | psql -d database2 -h host2
```

The line in the middle is a pipe, it takes the output from the first command and provides it as input to the second.